# Why is UDT transport deprecated in netty 4.1?

Tags: netty

I'm looking for the implementation of UDP based data transfer in Java. I was happy to find netty because it offers UDT transport.

But on the second look I saw that all classes under io.netty.channel.udt are deprecated.

What is the reason for this?
Does it makes sense to start development based on netty/udt or is there a better way?

Comment: If you check javadoc of any class under io.netty.channel.udt you will see `@deprecated The UDT transport is no longer maintained and will be removed.`

Comment: And indeed, it was removed in 5.x : https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/8578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From  the netty site, look at the 'get involved' menu.
- Go to GitHub.
- Search for one the deprecated files, e.g. NioUdtAcceptorChannel.java
- choose 'blame'
- find the line with the @deprecated attribute
- look at the comment

> #### Mark transport udt as deprecated as barchart-udt is not maintained anymore
>
> Motivation:
>
> barchart-udt is not maintained anymore so there is not way for us to
>   get fixes for udt. Because of this we should mark the transport as
>   deprecated.
>
> Modifications:
>
> Deprecate all udt classes.
>
> Result:
>
> transport udt is deprecated and so the user knows it will be removed
>   in the future.

https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/4734ef61a57b15df3e313b071956218fde98da2c

Barchart-udt is at https://github.com/barchart/barchart-udt and seems to have commits in the last year, so I'm not sure whether the reason is still valid.